# Make height auto element absolute in overflow hidden relative

Tags: css

I want to link the height of a div with the id #box1 to the height of an image contained within it. is this possible? Code below:

```
<div id="box1" style="overflow:hidden; position:relative; width:100%; height:auto">
    <div id="box2" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">
        <img src="images" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really unclear. Are we supposed to guess how your HTML and CSS look like?

Comment: <div id="box1" style="overflow:hidden; position:relative; width:100%; height:auto"><div id="box2" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;"><img src="images" /> </div></div>

Comment: Thanks for adding the code, Im however still not getting what you want to achieve....?

Comment: I make a slide responsive with a container overflow:hidden I can not height auto this container. I don't want use min-max height for that.

Comment: if you want to do this why you set position of box2 absolute ?

Comment: Thanks. Because I will make box2 slide left right images, apply slideshow

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you mean you want the height of #box1 to be the same height as the image inside it, not setting a height attribute on #box1 at all should achieve this?

Comment: Maybe consider selecting as answer and upvoting then? Thanks.